# AcControlType enumeration for multi valued combobox ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking for AcControlType enumeration for multi valued combobox. I refered to some official microsoft website(below link) and also other sites. I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me with this plz.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.accontroltype

Comment: There is no special `AcControlType` for multi valued combo box, because it has `acComboBox` value. Behavior of combo box depends on underlying field set in `ControlSource`.

Comment: Using a multi-value combobox means you have a multi-value field. Advise not to use multi-value fields.

Comment: thanks 4dmonster for the answer

Comment: @June7, I have the requirement to use multi value combobox, May I please know why it is not advised to use multi value combobox? or if there is any alternative to the multi value combobox?

Comment: Because multi-value fields are a pain to deal with. Among other reasons, if you ever want to migrate to another database platform, will be a real headache because none other have this feature. Alternative is a related dependent table. A multi-value field is really just a pointer to a hidden related table.

Comment: Thank you June7 for the information.

Comment: @June7, is there a link you could provide to me to understand about the alternative to the multi-value combobox?

Comment: The alternative is just normal relational database design. Any introductory tutorial should explain this. Use a form/subform arrangement for data entry/edit. Or choose to use multi-value field. Just understand what it really is and how to deal with it.